# What is $\text {Var} (Y)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Suppose that the lifetime of a machine is exponentially distributed with a mean value $20$ years. Suppose that you bought $10$ such machines and the lifetimes of the machines are independent. Let $Y$ be the number of machines that lasted longer than $30$ years. What is $\text {Var} (Y)?$

**My attempt** $:$ Let $X_i$ denote the lifetime of $i$-th machine for $1 \leq i \leq 10.$ Then $X_i$'s are iid with $X_i \sim \exp \left ( \frac {1} {20} \right ),$ for each $i.$ So the probability of a machine to last more than $30$ years is thus $$\int_{30}^{\infty} \frac {1} {20} e^{-\frac {x} {20}}\ dx = 1 - \frac {1} {20} \int_{0}^{30} e^{-\frac {x} {20}}\ dx = e^{-\frac {3} {2}}.$$

Then the random variable $Y$ is binomially distributed with $Y \sim \text {Bin} \left (10,e^{-\frac {3} {2}} \right ).$ So $\text {Var} (Y) = 10\ e^{-\frac 3 2} \left (1-e^{-\frac 3 2} \right ).$ Am I correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: Thanks @ParclyTaxel.

Answer (score 1):

The variance of a binomial distribution is given by $npq$, which is same as what you wrote in the last line. Hence it's correct.